# gulp-eslint not linting .js files inside of a dot directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, eslint, gulp-eslint

I have `.js` files inside of a dot directory that are not being linted by `gulp-eslint`.

Example: `.foo/file1.js`

I've confirmed that [the glob is picking up the files inside of the dot directory](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#dots).

`gulp-eslint` is passing successfully for the files inside of a parent dot directory even when an intentional error is introduced inside these files.

I've confirmed that directories without a `.` in the name of the directory (e.g. `src/file.js`, etc.) are failing linting, when the same intentional error is introduced.

My project structure is something like this:

```
project/
│
├── .foo/
│   ├──file1.js
│   └──file2.js
│
├── src/
│   ├──file1.js
│   └──file2.js
│
├── gulpfile.js
└── .eslintrc
```

Contents of `gulpfile.js`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('lint', () => {
    return gulp.src([ './src/**/*.js', './.foo/**/*.js' ])
        .pipe(eslint({
            configFile: './.eslintrc' 
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Contents of `.eslintrc`

```
// Reducing down to a single, simple rule
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there something incorrect in my config that is preventing the `.js` files inside of the dot directory `.foo` from being linted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a [known "quirk"](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12348) of eslint (as of `6.8.0`).

The workaround (until a PR is merged to fix this) is to use an `.eslintignore` file to unignore dot directories explicitly:

```
#.eslintignore
!.foo
```